# Store arrays of (unique)key-value in redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, redis

Users in the app are bonused/penalized points given certain events.

I'd like to store for each user:

1- List of Bonused `[EventID,#points]`

2- List of Penalized `[EventID,#points]`

#### Features

- Must be able to push new `[EventID, #points]` pairs to the lists.
- Can retrieve List of `EventID` easily.
- `#points` can be decimal, not just integer.

**E.g.**

User#10

- Bonuses: [ [122,10], [128,10], [133,5]]
- Penalization: [ [22,10], [28,5], [13,1]]

· **User#1** balance: (10+10+5)-(10+5+1) = 9

### Options so far

I'm using postgres + Redis.

#### 1. Postgres's HSTORE

E.g. `User.find(10).bonus_events => {'122':'10','128':'10','133':'5'}`

#### 2. Postgres's JSON type

E.g. `User.find(10).bonus_events =>
        [{id:'122',points:'10'},
         {id:'128',points:'10'}
         {id:'133',points:'5'}]`

#### 3. Redis ?

Not convinced...

Comment: Why not a unique list for both Bonused and Penalized and just have negative numbers for the penalizations?

Comment: @thepirat000 That's a good point, I thought about that too. But I'd need to render two tables: one for the events that penalize, and another for the events that bonus. I figure it's more efficient with two lists, since I won't have to search for scores<0 vs scores>0 every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ZSET case

The [ZSET](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) (Sorted Set) may be used in that way. In your question eventId and points are integers so Redis would store both with max possible effectivity.

From [datatypes intro](http://redis.io/topics/data-types):

> Redis Sorted Sets are non repeating collections of Strings. The difference is that every member of a Sorted Set is associated with score, that is used in order to take the sorted set ordered, from the smallest to the greatest score. While members are unique, scores may be repeated.
>
> With sorted sets you can add, remove, or update elements in a very fast way (in a time proportional to the logarithm of the number of elements). Since elements are taken in order and not ordered afterwards, you can also get ranges by score or by rank (position) in a very fast way. Accessing the middle of a sorted set is also very fast, so you can use Sorted Sets as a smart list of non repeating elements where you can quickly access everything you need: elements in order, fast existence test, fast access to elements in the middle!

Solution:

1. Use 2 ZSET per user - one for bonuses and one for penalization.
2. `EventID` is key and `#points` are score of ZSET.

Add events:

```
ZADD bonuses:1 10 122 
ZADD penalization:1 10 22
...
```

Agregate them (pseudocode):

```
function getBalance(userId) {
    bonusKey = "bonuses:" + userId;
    penalizationKey = "penalization:" + userIdl

    bonuses = redis.call("ZRANGE", bonusKey, 0 -1, "WITHSCORES")
    penalization = redis.call("ZRANGE", penalizationKey, 0 -1, "WITHSCORES")

    //`bonuses` and `penalization` are array of eventId->points,
    // so use index 1 to aceess just points
    return bonuses.reduse(acc, element => acc + element[1]) + 
           penalization.reduse(acc, element => acc + element[1]);
}
```

### HSET case

> **Use this case only if you have unique eventId in each list**

Redis Hashes are maps between string fields and string values, so they are the perfect data type to represent objects (e.g. A User with a number of fields like name, surname, age, and so forth). A hash with a few fields is stored in a way that takes very little space, so you can store millions of objects in a small Redis instance.

Solution:

1. Use 2 HSET per user - one for bonuses and one for penalization (use may think to store both list with one set with prefixes, for example bonus:eventId - do not do that. This do not allow redis to [use RAM effecient](http://redisplanet.com/redis/under-the-hood-of-redis-hash-part-1/)).
2. `EventID` is key and `#points` are value of HSET.

Add events:

```
HSET bonuses:1 122 10
HSET penalization:1 22 10
...
```

Agregate them (pseudocode):

```
function getBalance(userId) {
    bonusKey = "bonuses:" + userId;
    penalizationKey = "penalization:" + userIdl

    bonuses = redis.call("HGETALL", bonusKey)
    penalization = redis.call("HGETALL", penalizationKey)

    //`bonuses` and `penalization` are array of eventId->points,
    // so use index 1 to aceess just points
    return bonuses.reduse(acc, element => acc + element[1]) + 
           penalization.reduse(acc, element => acc + element[1]);
}
```

### What's better

HSET case use RAM better and faster. If you have just unique eventId in each list - use this case.

Comment: I forgot to mention that `#points` would be decimal numbers as well, not just integers. Therefore I guess Redis Hashes are the most appropiate data type. Great answer!